# R regexp swapping text parts

Tags: regex, r

I want to swap text parts from left to right and vice versa. This is working perfectly from left to right:

```
sub("(^x+)(.+)", "\\2\\1","xxxxx6.0")
[1] "6.0xxxxx"
```

while the other direction does not:

```
sub("(.+)(x+$)", "\\2\\1","6.0xxxxx")
[1] "x6.0xxxx"
```

What am I missing?

Comment: or you could split the string and reverse it `rev(strsplit("xxxxx6.0", '(?<=(x))(?!\\1)', perl=TRUE)[[1]])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue lies in your second regex. The second regex has a `.+` which is a greedy quantifier matching every single character. The first group would try to match as much as possible.

```
(6.0xxxx)(x)
```

The parentheses indicate the two groups that would get matched by your regex.

There are two ways to solve this. The first is to use a lazy quantifier instead of a greedy quantifier:

```
/(.+?)(x+$)/
```

The question mark makes the `+` lazy, only taking the fewest number of digits possible instead of the most. This would group like

```
(6.0)(xxxxx)
```

which is what you want.

The other option is to match, instead of every possible character, all characters that are not `x`.

```
/(^[^x]+)(+x$)/
```

The caret inside the matching group indicates that the matching group is inverted (match everything that is not x). This will match everything up to the first `x` as group 1, which will produce the desired groups.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a negative lookbehind `(?<!...)` for the second regex to get around the fact that `(.+)` is greedy.  The negative lookbehind makes it so that `(x+$)` won't match a character that is immediately preceded by `x`:

```
sub("(.+)(?<!x)(x+$)", "\\2\\1", "6.0xxxxx", perl=TRUE)
#[1] "xxxxx6.0"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, working perfect, a bit more complex than Strikeskids'. One upvote...